# Can you drop bottlecaps?

Tags: fallout-4

I've found a few lonely bottlecaps out on the wastelands, but I was wondering if you can get them out of your inventory onto a table to make, say, a bottlecap pyramid. As a bonus question I was also wondering if you could give your companions bottlecaps since I believe their efforts should be rewarded.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? While we take questions like this, we do expect some research on the OPs side. "Does not show research" is a common reason for downvoting, and it does not appear you have given any effort to see what happens, in game.

Comment: I tried and failed, but given that fallout 4 is a complex enough game I would rather ask and make sure. Plus I haven't seen this question asked anywhere else.

Comment: Since it is based on an existing engine from a rather popular game (Skyrim), you were not able to drop money there, and it doesn't seem like they added that function here yet.

Comment: If you tried and failed, please add that to your question, and any similar questions you ask in the future. You can get a better answer if people know what you already tried, and you'll get more upvotes on your questions. I don't think you can do this, like @Nelson said, but I haven't actually tried it yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot physically drop your own personal caps. This is due to the fact that they are no longer an item in your inventory like they were in Fallout 3.

The only way I have found place a single cap somewhere was to explode a bottlecap mine, which spawns roughly 30 caps, and proceed to drag them elsewhere. This only worked for me because I didn't need very many caps. I was only making a Nuka cola display in my house. If you need more than this you'll need both a lot of bottlecap mines and a lot of time and patience. This is the only way I have found so far hope this helps.

PS. if you just so happen to accidentally pick up one of the caps while moving them you take them all including the ones you placed so try to save often when moving them otherwise prepared to be triggered.

Comment: I can't believe someone actually answered with a solution to my question. Lemme just take my hat off a second over here.

Comment: No problem man took me about an hour to figure it out lol

Comment: If I remember to try it later, I'll make my companions take the caps if they can. Thirty caps should cover weeks of soaking bullets as decoys + medical expenses.

Answer (score 2):

You can reward companions with caps (just for the feel; they don't use them or comment about it). In any settlement that provides caps, simply empty the workshop (except for caps) and order the company to inspect the workshop; they take the caps and store them in their inventory. My Cait got around 10K in pocket.

Answer (score 0):

There's one way to store your caps but not in a pile. Simply build shops and they will be stored in the shop. If you want your caps back, scrap the shop and the caps will appear in your workshop inventory.